# Creating a tag for all asp.net MVC questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

As a fan of ASP.NET MVC, I find myself checking out questions across the different asp.net mvc tags (asp.net mvc; mvc2; ,vc3; mvc4) on Stack Overflow.

I find myself spending time editing posts (to include more tags) that are only tagged with the one the user happens to implement, but deal with helpers or routes -- issues that are universal to the framework and not to a specific version.

I suggest having a tag like ASP.NET MVC Universal which makes a post view-able from *all* these separate but basically same tags.

Similarly, I would like to view a page that includes all MVC posts so I don't waste time jumping from tag to tag.

**Side Point:** Same logic and rational applies to the Entity-Framework tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards work in favourite tags, so you can add "asp.net-mvc*" for your favourites and it'll do more or less what you want.

For example, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc*) now shows all questions with tags that start with "asp.net-mvc".

Technically, there already is a universal tag for ASP.NET MVC: [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). I don't have a strong opinion on whether or not version-specific tags are useful, though. I prefer to just use wildcards as described above.

Comment: OIC. Didn't realize. As a counter, I don't think the community at large understands that either. I will now edit users posts using wildcard, but most users will continue to make this mistake. I wonder if there should at least be an option to include wildcard?

Comment: @DaveA Wildcards are only useful for *viewing* posts. Don't include them in the tags themselves.

Comment: thanks that helps. But again, On the other side, I find that users choose specific forums and their questions don't get proper visibility. Maybe there should be a more clear aggregating choice on viewing questions. As usefull as wildcard is, I would never have guessed.

Comment: @DaveA Yeah, unfortunately it's a bit obscure far as features go.

Comment: Don't mean to be a debbie-downer, but I feel like there is a need here. Maybe question/post should be altered, but I'd like to see somekind of aggregating feature that doesnt depend on user to know better...

Comment: i tried using the wildcard to search asp.net-mvc* and it wont work. the form wont even submit when i hit enter. On the upside, I did learn to stay away from meta and just stick to stack. I ask a legit Q negged.

Comment: @DaveA What form are you talking about? Go to your [Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1212341), type in "asp.net-mvc*" in the Favourite Tags textbox and click Add.

Comment: will do, thanks again

Comment: i went to tags, and tried typing asp.net-mvc*. that form didnt except asp.net-mvc*